# Calculate and draw route on Bing Maps control

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps

in my app for WP7(mango) I need to navigate the user from one point to another. I know there is the Map control that lets you draw staff on it, but how do you ask it to draw the path for you? (based on the specified destination & user's current location - but that keeps changing so how do you update the route if he goes of the way?)

Comment: You're basically asking 3 questions in one here. Next time, ask *one* detailed question, so you can get a more concise answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To update the map with the users current location, use the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` and update the position of a databound Pushpin as it changes. Remember to set the minimum distance to something low, like 5 meters.

A pushpin like the one on bing maps, can be created with this XAML template:

```
<maps:Pushpin Background="{StaticResource PushpinLocationBrush}"
              Location="{Binding MyLocation}">
    <maps:Pushpin.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Width="15"
                           Height="15"
                           Margin="0"
                           Fill="Black">
                    <Rectangle.Projection>
                        <PlaneProjection CenterOfRotationX="0"
                                         LocalOffsetX="-2"
                                         LocalOffsetY="5"
                                         RotationZ="45" />
                    </Rectangle.Projection>
                </Rectangle>
                <Ellipse Width="7"
                         Height="7"
                         Margin="0"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Fill="Orange"
                         RenderTransformOrigin="0.339,0.232"
                         StrokeThickness="0" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </maps:Pushpin.Template>
</maps:Pushpin>
```

Getting the GeoCoordinate of a address can be done with Bing Maps. You can read more about Bing Services here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980922.aspx -- the one you need is the [GeoCodeService](http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc)

Drawing a path is rather complicated, specially if you want it to follow the roads. For this, you need the Bing Maps Route Service.

Add the service to Visual Studio, with `RouteServiceReference` as name, and then you can utilize following code to get the path fragments, and add them to your map. The XAML below reflects the controls I add the fragments to:

```
List<GeoCoordinate> locations = new List<GeoCoordinate>();

RouteServiceClient routeService = new RouteServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IRouteService");

routeService.CalculateRouteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    var points = e.Result.Result.RoutePath.Points;
    var coordinates = points.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude));

    var routeColor = Colors.Blue;
    var routeBrush = new SolidColorBrush(routeColor);

    var routeLine = new MapPolyline()
    {
        Locations = new LocationCollection(),
        Stroke = routeBrush,
        Opacity = 0.65,
        StrokeThickness = 5.0,
    };

    foreach (var location in points)
    {
        routeLine.Locations.Add(new GeoCoordinate(location.Latitude, location.Longitude));
    }

    RouteLayer.Children.Add(routeLine);
};

RouteBingMap.SetView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(locations));

routeService.CalculateRouteAsync(new RouteRequest()
{
    Credentials = new Credentials()
    {
        ApplicationId = "YOURBINGMAPSKEYHERE"
    },
    Options = new RouteOptions()
    {
        RoutePathType = RoutePathType.Points
    },
    Waypoints = new ObservableCollection<Waypoint>(
        locations.Select(x => new Waypoint()
        {
            Location = x.Location
        }))
});
```

Related XAML:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="RouteBingMap"
          AnimationLevel="None"
          CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed"
          CredentialsProvider="YOURBINGMAPSKEYHERE"
          LogoVisibility="Collapsed"
          ZoomBarVisibility="Collapsed"
          ZoomLevel="12">
    <maps:MapLayer x:Name="RouteLayer" />
</maps:Map>
```