# Drawing a route on Bing Maps in WP7 Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, routes, bing-maps

I need to draw a route from my position to a predefined location on a Bing Map. I've read carefully this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680787/1233659

But I'm new to WP7, can anybody please tell me the step before using that code; how to add and use the service .

And will that answer be sufficient to draw the rout? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need an account for the bing maps api: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ If you have an account for bing maps you can request an authorization key, to use bing maps

then you add a webreference to your project that points to: http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/routeservice/routeservice.svc

If you added the reference you can use the code that is provided in the answer you linked. If you want additional information about the route servive you can find it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966826.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981072.aspx

Hope this helps