# WP 7.1 show route from coordinates on map

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps, windows-phone-7.8

I want to be able to display a route on a map, using a list of GeoCoordinates i already have.
I have looked at Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls, but it doesn't seem to work on WP 7.1. 
Instead using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps i am able to display the map, but i don't know what to do from here.

Googling also results in people talking about SilverLight Bing Map control, but i'm not really sure wether this is something completely different and if i should use this instead.

Thanks

Comment: See answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675313/calculate-and-draw-route-on-bing-maps-control

Comment: The answer to that question uses MapPolyline to draw the line on the map. As far as i know, MapPolyline is in Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls which isn't avalible in WP 7.1.

Comment: For Wp7 it is in Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps (not  Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls which is the map namespace for wp8) furthermore if you read the tags (and the question) you will see that the link i posted is about wp7.1 not another platform